# Drag all windows from an app to another workspace

Tags: 20.04, gnome, workspaces, wayland, macosx

I'm missing a *Workspaces* feature from *macOS*:
*grouping windows **by app***.

The benefit is a declutter of *"Activities & Workspaces"* view, displaying windows from the same application all grouped together.

[image: macOS Mission Control showing multiple windows from Safari, that are grouped in a cluster and overlay each other; the windows from other applications belong to distinct cluster]
<sup>(see Safari & iChat windows: all windows from an app can be moved by dragging the app icon to another workspace)</sup>

*macOS* allows to drag'n'drop a single window to another workspace; or to move ***all*** the windows altogether.

*Ubuntu GNOME* seems to handle only one window per time. This is cumbersome when having many windows for one application.

---

I'm wondering:

1. **is it possible to move in another workspace all the windows of a specific application altogether?**
2. **is it possible to display the windows group by application, in the "Activities" view?**